# Cassandra column family not found in pycassa

Tags: python, cassandra, pycassa

I'm attempting to connect to Cassandra in order to do a bulk insert. However, when I attempt to connect, I get an error.

The code I'm using:

```
from pycassa import columnfamily
from pycassa import pool

cassandra_ips = ['<an ip addr>']
conpool = pool.ConnectionPool('my_keyspace', cassandra_ips)

colfam = columnfamily.ColumnFamily(conpool, 'my_table')
```

However this fails on that last line with:

```
pycassa.cassandra.ttypes.NotFoundException: NotFoundException(_message=None, why='Column family my_table not found.')
```

The column family definitely exists:

```
cqlsh> use my_keyspace
   ... ;
cqlsh:my_keyspace> desc tables;

my_table

cqlsh:my_keyspace>
```

And I don't think this is a simple typo on the table name, as I've check it a dozen times, but also because of this:

```
In [3]: sys_mgr = pycassa.system_manager.SystemManager(cassandra_ips[0])

In [4]: sys_mgr.get_keyspace_column_families('my_keyspace')
Out[4]: {}
```

Why is that `{}`?

If it matters:

- The table/column family was created using CQL.
- The table is currently empty.
- The table was roughly created using:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE my_table (
    user_id int,
    year_month int,
    t timestamp,
    <tons of other attributes>
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, year_month), t)
  ) WITH compaction =
      { 'class' : 'LeveledCompactionStrategy', 'sstable_size_in_mb' : 160 };
  ```

Comment: What version of casssandra are you using?

Comment: @Drewness Cassandra 2.0.5

Comment: Was `my_table` created with compact storage?

Comment: @Drewness I didn't specify that. (At least, I don't think I did.) I've added the CQL statement roughly used to create the table, omitting a few of the columns.

Comment: Try it with `) WITH COMPACT STORAGE;`

Comment: @Drewness That works, and it shows up in pycassa. However, my first attempt failed with "Bad Request: COMPACT STORAGE with composite PRIMARY KEY allows no more than one column not part of the PRIMARY KEY (got: <list of my columns>)" — does that mean I can only use a single column? (I'd need to break all my columns into separate tables?)

Comment: Yes, partially. I'll type it all up in an answer.

Comment: @Thanatos you might be interested to use [this python driver](http://github.com/datastax/python-driver) which is a better fit (imo and "biasedly") for current versions of C*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access CQL3 databases via a thrift API, such as pycassa, the tables must be created using compact storage.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
...
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE;
```

With regards to the primary keys, from the [docs](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/create_table_r.html):

> Using the compact storage directive prevents you from defining more
>   than one column that is not part of a compound primary key.

Currently you are using a [composite partition key](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/create_table_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_v3f_vfk_xj__p_sks_qcr_2k) but enabling compact storage limits us to using a *compound* partition key. So you will **not** have to limit it to a single column, it just has to be part of the compound key. One final [reference](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/thrift-to-cql3).

Comment: The remainder of my columns aren't part of a key into my data (they're just normal attributes): how do you mean they can be used as part of the key?

Comment: Currently your using a composite key, `((user_id, year_month), t)`. So you could exclude the timestamp _or_ make it into a compound key like `(user_id, year_month, t)`.

Answer (score 0):

This case could happen also after creation CF named with uppercase: 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/ucase-lcase_r.html

I had such strange structure of namespace with quoted CFs:

```
cqlsh:testkeyspace> DESC TABLES;

"Tabletest"  users  "PlayerLastStats"
```

I got error on pycassa `system_manager.create_column_family(...)`  but only if here was column_validation_classes parameter

```
pycassa.cassandra.ttypes.NotFoundException: NotFoundException(_message=None, why='Column family NewTable not found.')
```

After renaming to lowercase all tables looked good

```
cqlsh:testkeyspace> DESC TABLES;

tabletest  newtable  users  playerlaststats
```